# updating button text and other issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to update my button.  but the problem is that I can't have an ID/name with it, right, when doing this?  so what if I have multiple forms on the page, and must identify the button?

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload my File" style="background-color:#00F; font-size:14px; padding:1em;" onclick="
    this.value='Please wait...';
    this.disabled = true;
    var theForm = this.form;
    window.setTimeout(function(){theForm.submit();},3);" />
```

also, the button doesn't seem to wait 3 seconds when I hit the submit button.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout - delay is in milliseconds.

Comment: The `3` should be `3000` for a 3-second delay. Also, why couldn't you have an ID for the button?

Comment: here is what i'm trying to get to work: `<input type="submit" value="Upload my File" id="uploadFile" style="background-color:#00F; font-size:14px; padding:1em;" onclick="
    this.value='Please wait...';
    this.disabled = true;
    var theForm = this.form;
    window.setTimeout(function(){theForm.submit();},3000);" />` and then for the php, `if (isset($_POST['uploadFile'])) { echo "good";` the "good" is not being outputted on button click.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 u have specified as the time for delay is in milliseconds, to submit form after 3 seconds pass 3000. 1000ms = 1 second